# In Breeze, what is the best way to raise every column of a matrix to a power?

Tags: scala, linear-algebra, scala-breeze

Let's say I have a matrix like `[a1 a2 a3 a4]`, where the `ai`'s are the columns, and a sequence of Ints like `(p1, p2, p3, p4)`. What is the best way to create the matrix `[a1^p1 a2^p2 a3^p3 a4^p4]`?

Ultimately, the output I need is a vector where the entries are the products of the rows of the matrix `[a1^p1 a2^p2 a3^p3 a4^p4]`.

I've tried a bunch of different ways using `mapValues`, `mapPairs`, `map`, and `product`, but they all seem kind of hacky.